# creating a web deployment package for my asp.net mvc , is raising an error that it can not copy a file

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4, web-deployment

I am working on an asp.net mvc web application, and i tried to create a new Web Deployment Package for my project inside visual studio 2012. but i got the following error :-

```
Error   1   Copying file Views\Customer\Index.cshtml to obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\Views\Customer\Index.cshtml failed. Could not find file 'Views\Customer\Index.cshtml'.       0   0    Scanning
```

[image]

although the file `Views\Customer\Index.cshtml` exists, and even if it does not exsits why it will try to copy it ?